# How to affect ime-mode in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I wrote codes in jqGrid navGrid as following, but i can't change ime-mode by css.
What is mistake my code ?

```
$("#schedule").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager_schedule',
// Add Options 
.........
onInitializeForm: function(form) {

  $("#dt_start").css("ime-mode", "inactive");
  $("#nm_location").css("ime-mode", "active");

  $("#dt_start, #dt_end, #cd_location, #nm_link").bind("focus", function (){
  $(this).css("ime-mode", "inactive");
});

},
beforeInitData: function(form) {
  $("#dt_start").css("ime-mode", "inactive");
  $("#nm_location").css("ime-mode", "active");
},
beforeShowForm: function(form) {
  $("#dt_start").css("ime-mode", "inactive");
  $("#nm_location").css("ime-mode", "active");
}
}
);
```

Comment: The problem solved by myself.

Comment: The problem solved by myself.　I defined the css .imeoff {ime-mode: inactive;} and .imeon {ime-mode: active;}. modified the code using addClass or removeClass. and now working correctly I intend.

Answer (score 0):

It is because that ime-mode is NOT one of the standard properties in css. It only works for IE and FF. So it is not supported by the jQuery.css().